# Android studio does not free java memory

Tags: android-studio

Every time I make my project (Build -> Make project) or run my app (Run -> Run 'app') java memory increase and it is never released.

After 10 builds the memory is almost in 1GB and every 30 minutes I need to force java to close:

[image]

What am I missing? My android studio is 1.1.0.

Comment: See https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/fixing-memory-leaks-android-studio-albert-lai

Comment: @BadZen Thanks, but the problem is not in my app since the java memory increases even when I don't run my app. And in my case I 'm running in my  phone, not in my computer.